# Laravel route with 2 params

Tags: php, laravel

I has structure of routes:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}', 'AppController');
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/projects/{projectId}', 'ProjectsController');
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/task/{taskId}', 'TasksController');
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/bugs/{bugId}', 'BugsController');
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/comments/{commentId}', 'CommentsController');
    Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/calendar', 'CalendarController');
    Route::controller('/', 'CompaniesController');
});
```

But when i'm trying to open /app/3/project/1 it's not working:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
Controller method not found.
```

What could cause this problem?

**Right solution: check right order of your routes(longest mut be in top):**

```
Route::controller('app/{companyId}/project/{projectId}', 'ProjectsController');
Route::controller('app/{companyId}/task/{taskId}', 'TasksController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/bugs/{bugId}', 'BugsController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/comments/{commentId}', 'CommentsController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/calendar', 'CalendarController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}', 'AppController');
Route::controller('/', 'CompaniesController');
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to using the Laravel routing system. You are trying to do http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers when really you just want named routes like http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 1):

Little bit of experiements, and I found bug. Reason was in position of routes. This works.

```
Route::controller('app/{companyId}/project/{projectId}', 'ProjectsController');
Route::controller('app/{companyId}/task/{taskId}', 'TasksController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/bugs/{bugId}', 'BugsController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/comments/{commentId}', 'CommentsController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/calendar', 'CalendarController');
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}', 'AppController');
Route::controller('/', 'CompaniesController');
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your answer as the solution, this can be useful for other users :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

first at all you must specify the route method (get or post), then you must join with @ the action name will be executed in the specified controller

```
Route::get('/app/{companyId}/bugs/{bugId}', 'BugsController@actionname');
```